# how to change zIndex .dragndrop question

Tags: javascript, jquery

first, have to look at this dragndrop (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-drag-and-drop/)

what i want to ask is , isit possible to add a ACTIVE "window" onClick???

example:

i got 3 window dragable, name drag1 , drag2 and drag3

drag1 zIndex="98"

drag2 zIndex="99"

drag3 zIndex="100"

when i click on the drag1, change the drag1 zIndex value to highest than all the other drag.

after that,

i click drag3, also change the drag3 zIndex value to highest than all the other drag.

also high than the drag1

example2:

set a ACTIVE drag onClick???

Comment: What do you mean by active window? And how does it fit into the drag-and-drop scenario?

Comment: Wait, how is this addon any different from the jqueryui draggable and droppable? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: erm...what i mean is...

like Windows,the Always on Top function

Comment: i don't know what the different from drag'n'drop and jqueryui draggable and droppable

Comment: So you want it so that whichever one you are dragging gets the highest z-index so that it hovers over everything and when dropped is on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you are going for. You should use the jqueryui method [`draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). It has an option [`stack`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack) that automatically gives the dragged item the highest z-index.

### example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.boxes').draggable({stack:{group: ".boxes", min:100}});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    background-color: #fffac0;
    border: 2px dashed #fffa0d;
}
    .boxes {
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         border: 1px solid #bbb;
     }
     #box1 {
         background-color: red;
     }
     #box2 {
         background-color: green;
     }
     #box3 {
         background-color: blue;
     }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box1" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="boxes"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="boxes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently the zindex either has to be set in the css or in the stack hash, so I've updated it to reflect that.